# Accessing Webdav on Windows Server 2008 R2 with XP

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-xp, webdav

We have IIS 7.5, with webdav enabled, installed on our file server (FS1).  We have multiple Virtual Directories. When trying to connect to 2 of the VD's through network places on XP machines it says the network location is unavailable. However if I map the root of the server on a windows 7 machine and browse to the directory the webdav will then work on the xp machines.

Has anyone experienced this issue or willing to help?

Comment: Make sure that the webclient service on the workstation is running.

Comment: thanks, it is running, I can use webdav after the windows 7 machine has browsed to the drive without any changes to the xp machine. It's like windows 7 is 'waking up' the connection.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Believe it or not giving the IIS_IUSRS group permission over the share fixed the problem.